# Where is a good place to farm metal shards?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

I'd like to purchase a Shadow weapon from a merchant and while I have the couple of rare components needed, I am short a lot of metal shards.  While I could go out and hunt random beasts for their metal shards, I was wondering if there's a particularly good place to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some tips for farming shards from [here](https://www.gameskinny.com/ofsyu/horizon-zero-dawn-tip-guide-how-to-farm-10000-shards-per-hour) and a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/horizon/comments/7qehpe/easiest_way_to_get_metal_shards/)

Here is one:

> 1. Buy the **Shadow Sharpshot Bow**
> 2. Craft **Harvester Arrows**
> 3. Return to the first hunting ground you run into (with the Watchers and Grazers).
> 4. Choose the trial that requires you to shoot a certain number of Blaze Canisters off the backs of Grazers.
> 5. Take the rope down, then stealth kill the entire herd with your spear.
> 6. Once they're dead, go to each body and shoot off all 4 Blaze Canisters with the Harvester Arrow.
> 7. Loot all bodies and pick up the canisters off the ground.
> 8. Speak to the Trial Giver and restart the Trial.
> 9. Rinse and repeat the kill/harvest cycle.

Answer (score 0):

A great way that I always did is to farm thunderjaws ( it's actually pretty easy ) all you need is tearblast arrows and some good aim. How? You aim for the disc launchers on his back. Tearblast them down. Pick them up. Shoot him using them. He's gonna be down in a matter of seconds. Each one you loot is gonna have 157 metal shards, and the hole action doesn't take but 3-5 minutes, do that for a while and you will quickly be able to buy the best equipment from merchants. Wish you luck ;)